# Julia Data Frames Sort

Tags: python, dataframe, julia

If I can pry you away from your Google Glasses Lawnmover Man conversion for a few seconds. Let's say I have a data set with 10 columns. I would like to winnow the data set down to only rows where Col 5 has a value of greater than 47. How would I do that? In Pandas, it's pretty straightforward:

```
df2 = df[df.Response > 47]
```

Is there a Julia equivalent? Thanks in advance as always.

Comment: I have to ask, what is a Google Glass Lawnmover Man conversion?

Comment: it's a transformation that will be common in the next 3-5 years where nerds go from being awkward with women to players overnight with the help of technology and wealth.

Comment: Note that you could also write `df.query("Response > 47")`.  Passing a string allows us to get around limitations in Python syntax which Julia doesn't suffer from.  (I'm quite envious of the lispy things they can do.)

Comment: Yes impossible to do enough lispy things in this life. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(Treatment = rand(10)*100, Response = rand(10)*100)
df2 = df[df[:Response] .> 47, :]
```

Comment: This worked as well but seemed a little roundabout.....x=find(df[“Time”] .>= 3)
sub(df, x)